# React setState after a certain time without losing the typing content and displaying it without the delay

Tags: reactjs

So, I'm in a scenario where I need to collect the input from the onChange, but set it only when the user finishes typing on React, for example, we collect the state and then just set the state to what we've collected, because I'm having multiple components, big ones, multi-rendering is of them all, is making the input slower, in my case the input is something else much complicated, but I used on this demo the native input just to explain my self.

Here it is my demo app:

```
import { StrictMode, useState } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  const setItAfterSomeTime = (value) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setInput(value);
    }, [1000]);
  };

  // same as use effect
  console.log(input);

  return (
    <input
      placeholder="Anything here..."
      value={input}
      onChange={(e) => setItAfterSomeTime(e.target.value)}
    />
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

Hero is the sandbox also: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-cloud-js5hf7

Comment: If your app consists of multiple forms, you can consider to use library such as react-hook-form or formik ?

Comment: And if you want to only set the value when typing is finished, you could use `onBlur` event handler on `<input/>`

Comment: But that is kinda tricky, becasue you need to click outside the component right

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is called debouncing/throttling. This lib could be helpful https://github.com/nkbt/react-debounce-input

You can also implement it yourself using this hook https://usehooks.com/useDebounce/

Or from scratch, as explained in this article https://blog.logrocket.com/how-and-when-to-debounce-or-throttle-in-react/